# Running Keras using theano

Tags: python, keras, theano

I have followd the link provided by Keras to download theano backend [link](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html)on windows (mine is windows 10). but when I import Kares. I got the followings:

```
Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:

"C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe" -shared -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -DMS_WIN64 -I"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Python27\include" -I"C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\theano\gof" -L"C:\Python27\libs" -L"C:\Python27" -o C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-64\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp -lpython27

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\M\Desktop\Experiment_Calculation.py", line 5, in <module>

import  keras

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>

from . import activations

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\keras\activations.py", line 4, in <module>

from . import backend as K

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>

from .theano_backend import *

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 3, in <module>

import theano

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>

from theano.compile import (

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>

from theano.compile.function_module import *

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 21, in <module>

import theano.compile.mode

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py", line 10, in <module>

import theano.gof.vm

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 662, in <module>

from . import lazylinker_c

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 127, in <module>

preargs=args)

File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2316, in compile_str

(status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))

Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
.  #include <Python.h>
.  ^
.
```

I don't get the issue, Can Anyone please help with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above problem by editting the path enviroments, because I figured out that I have two version of Mingw. Thus, I removed the old one.

However, I got another error while downloading Kares following the link [link]

The error is as follows:

```
running develop
running egg_info
writing dependency_links to Keras.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing Keras.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing requirements to Keras.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to Keras.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'Keras.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'Keras.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating c:\python\python35\lib\site-packages\Keras.egg-link (link to .)
Keras 2.0.4 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed c:\users\m\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras
Processing dependencies for Keras==2.0.4
Searching for scipy>=0.14
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/
Best match: scipy 0.19.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/e5/93/9a8290e7eb5d4f7cb53b9a7ad7b92b9827ecceaddfd04c2a83f195d8767d/scipy-0.19.0.zip#md5=91b8396231eec780222a57703d3ec550
Processing scipy-0.19.0.zip
Writing C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dqpyaq0f\scipy-0.19.0\setup.cfg
Running scipy-0.19.0\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir 
C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dqpyaq0f\scipy-0.19.0\egg-dist-tmp-ebc75q91
C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dqpyaq0f\scipy-0.19.0\setup.py:323: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with "
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
yield saved
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
yield
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 273, in run
return func()
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
_execfile(setup_script, ns)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
exec(code, globals, locals)
File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dqpyaq0f\scipy-0.19.0\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dqpyaq0f\scipy-0.19.0\setup.py", line 396, in setup_package
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
packages=find_packages())
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py", line 34, in run
self.install_for_development()
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py", line 133, in install_for_development
self.process_distribution(None, self.dist, not self.no_deps)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 717, in process_distribution
[requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 826, in resolve
dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1092, in best_match
return self.obtain(req, installer)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1104, in obtain
return installer(requirement)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 640, in easy_install
return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 670, in install_item
dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 850, in install_eggs
return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1078, in build_and_install
self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1064, in run_setup
run_setup(setup_script, args)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 246, in run_setup
raise
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
yield
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
saved_exc.resume()
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
yield saved
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
yield
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 273, in run
return func()
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
_execfile(setup_script, ns)
File "C:\Python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
exec(code, globals, locals)
File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dqpyaq0f\scipy-0.19.0\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dqpyaq0f\scipy-0.19.0\setup.py", line 396, in setup_package
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I don't know why is this occuring. I have numpy intalld already. 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: All these problems were solved. Thanks. by returning to the same link